# Django model design pattern - get youngest related object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Django lets you follow relations [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), but none of the filter methods let you get youngest/oldest, or max/min, afaik.

Laravel has "[has one of many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)", and I wish that Django had something similar without requiring [window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions), that have their own limitations.

Annotations despite being promising, are also a dead end.

Therefore I wonder what the best design is for the following situation:

I have "model A", whose instances will pass through several statuses during their lifecycle ("created", "processing", "complete"). I want to know what status an instance of model A currently has, but also have a record of when each status was in effect. I don't want to parse logs.

I thought a good approach was to create a status model (model B) whose foreign key is a model A instance. it becomes easy to see when each status was started and stopped.

However if I want to get the current status (an instance of model B) for all my model A instances, I need to do n+1 database queries. This seems sub-optimal.

What are some alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However if I want to get the current status (an instance of model B) for all my model A instances, I need to do n+1 database queries. This seems sub-optimal.

**No**, you can make use of [**`Subquery`** expressions <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). Indeed, if you have two models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class ItemStatus(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    started = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You can annotate each `Item` with the last status with:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Item.objects.annotate(
    last_status=Subquery(
        ItemStatus.objects.filter(
            item_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-started').values('status')[:1]
    )
)
```

For each `Item`, there will be an extra attribute named `.last_status` that will contain the `.status` of the related `ItemStatus` that started last. If there is no such `StatusItem`, `last_status` will be `None` (`NULL`).

This will be determined by *subqueries* at the database side, hence it is done in the *same* query where you retrieve the `Item`s, and thus does not suffer from the *N+1 problem*.